# How can I force Angular 7+ Material Autocomplete to enter letters only provided by a data source?

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

**Edit:** There are some workarounds as posted below (see answers) for template-driven forms. (I am looking for a solution for reactive forms).

---

How can I force Angular Material Autocomplete to enter letters only provided by a data source?

[>> See the whole app here at stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k35drc?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts)

"Adel" is initial value and it is provided by the options-array:

```
options: User[] = [
    {name: 'George Michael'},
    {name: 'Aretha Franklin'},
    {name: 'Adel'},
    {name: 'Janet Jackson'},
  ];
```

The auto-complete works properly:

[image]

However, the following should not be possible:

[image]

The user may only enter the letters corresponding to an entry in the list, i. the first letters of an existing entry.

If the user attempts to enter letters that do not correspond to any of the existing values, an error message should inform the user: "The entered value must correspond to a list entry".

Is there possibility to do that with Angular Material Autocomplete?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop mat-autocomplete to take custom user input values apart from given options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425706/how-to-stop-mat-autocomplete-to-take-custom-user-input-values-apart-from-given-o)

Comment: @PatrykUszyński the solutions are too old, It must be Angular & Angular Material ^7, I'll update the title. As you see there are no accepted answers. Please don't be overly zealous, thank you!

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3334#issuecomment-469718514

Comment: @PatrykUszyński Maybe that's currently the only possible way -> writing an own directive, thank you. But the solution is for a template-driven form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem with a custom validator. [If you want to see it, here,..](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k35drc-hq95d3?file=validators%2Fauto-complete-validators.ts)

**In the list but case sensitive:**

[image: Case Sensitive]

**Wrong Value**

[image: Wrong Value]

**Everything is OK**

[image: Everythin is OK]

Answer (score 0):

It might be more efficient to trap the key entry at input time by adding a keydown handler to the input. Then look ahead at what the value would be and compare it to the list, 'cancelling' the event if necessary. Crudely:

```
<input (keydown)="keydownHandler($event)" ...


keydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  const character = event.key;
  if (character.length === 1) {

    let value = this.myForm.controls.myControl.value;
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      value = value.name;
    }

    value = (value + character).toLowerCase();

    if (!this.options.some(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) === 0)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  } 
}
```

This works with any kind of form.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k35drc-3edxqx)

Comment: thank you, your solution works properly but is not user-friendly. :/ I've written a custom validator, to solve that problem.

Comment: why not :) I'd love to!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following method that does not require to check the elements in entire list.

[Angular Material Autocomplete Component Force Selection: Complete Example](https://onthecode.co.uk/force-selection-angular-material-autocomplete/)

Here is the demo code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-force-selection-autocomplete-component)